# set -o vi при подключении по ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли добавить настройку на мой VPS таким образом, чтобы при подключении по ssh по умолчанию загружался bash c set -o vi и мне не надо было прописывать его вручную?

Операционная система на VPS - Ubuntu Linux.

Спасибо

Comment: А что мешает прописать его в `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько способов сделать это:

1. Добавить команду в `~/.bashrc`
   Тогда при стратке консоли выполняется `~/.bashrc` для данного пользователя
2. Создать `/etc/profile.d/myCommands.sh`
   прописать туда нужные вам команды. Будет выполняться для всех пользователей.
3. Добавить выполнения команды в `/etc/bashrc`
   Будет выполняться для всех пользователей.

Я рекомендую воспользоваться 1 пунктом. Но если вам надо, чтобы это работало под другими пользователями, например, root, то воспользуйтесь 2 или 3 пунктами.

Answer (score 0):

помимо уже предложенного можно явно указать опцию при подключении:

```
$ ssh user@server bash -o vi
```